# Chain Rule with variable in inner and outer function

Tags: derivatives, chain-rule

I want to find the derivative of the function:
$h(x) = x^2(x+1)$

We know that the correct derivative is $h'(x) = 3x^2+2x$

I want to know if **chain rule** can as well be applied here: $h′(x)=f′(g(x))∗g′(x)$

Can we say the following?

We have the **inner function $g(x)$**, which adds one to the argument:

$g(x) = x+1$

And we have the **outer function $f(x)$**, which multiplies the argument by $x^2$:

$f(x) = x^2*x$ (or better write $f(y) = x^2*y$ to avoid confusion?).

But if I proceed and say $f'(x)=3x^2$ and $g'(x) = 1$, then $h′(x)=f′(g(x))∗g′(x) = 3(x+1)^2*1=3x^2+6x+3 \neq 3x^2+2x$

Please let me know where I am wrong and if chain rule is applicable here at all.
I know that in this situation product rule is better to be used here. But if chain rule cannot be applied here, please explain where the logic breaks.

PS. I have seen a similar question here [Finding derivative using product and chain rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/568545/finding-derivative-using-product-and-chain-rule) and it implies that chain rule may be used.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the chain rule, since $h(x)=f(x)g(x), $ a product (!).

Comment: You are confusing composition of functions with products.

Comment: But why can't we say that product is a special case of composition? 
Can't we say that a product is a function, which multiplies some argument (which can as well be a function) by some value?

Comment: Of course we can!  Let $p\colon\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R$ defined by $p(x,y)=x\cdot y$.  Then $$\nabla p(x,y)= \begin{pmatrix} y\\x\end{pmatrix}.$$  For real-valued functions $f$ and $g$ we get from the cain rule $$p(f, g)= \langle \begin{pmatrix} g\\f\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix} f'\\g'\end{pmatrix}\rangle=gf'+fg'.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'trick' is that you have to apply the multivariate version of the chain rule.  When function is a composition of a bivariate function with arguments that each are monovariate functions :

$${[f\circ (g,h)]'(x) = \bigl[g'\cdot f^{(1,0)}\circ(g,h)+h'\cdot f^{(0,1)}\circ(g,h)\bigr](x)}$$

---

Now let $h(x) = f(x, x+1)$ where $f(x,y)=x^2y$. $$h(x)= x^2~(x+1)$$

Then we have the partial derivatives $f^{(1,0)}(x,y)=2xy$ and $f^{(0,1)}(x,y)=x^2$ .

$${f^{(1,0)}(x,x+1)=2x~(x+1)\\f^{(0,1)}(x,x+1)=x^2}$$

The above chain rule gives us: $$\begin{align}h'(x) &= (x)' f^{(1,0)}(x,x+1)+ (x+1)' f^{(0,1)}(x,x+1)\\&= 2x~(x+1)+x^2\\&=3x^2+2x\end{align}$$